# PHP parse REQUEST_URI into array

Tags: php, regex

I am parsing the REQUEST_URI into an array.

Right now i have the following code:

```
private function load_url_vars()
{
    if (preg_match('/^.+\?(.+)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $matches))
    {
        $varpairs = preg_split("/&/", $matches[1]);
        foreach ($varpairs as $varpair)
        {
            if (preg_match('/^([A-Za-z_]+)=(.*)$/', $varpair, $varmatch))
            {
                $this->urlvars[$varmatch[1]] = urldecode($varmatch[2]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any security concerns by doing it this way? Is this a good way of parsing it?

Edit: language

Comment: There are no security concerns, but you already get all that in _GET superglobal so what's the point of your code?

Comment: when using mod_rewrite it's better to parse it in php, than in .htaccess

Comment: I've read all current comments and you're wrong in your idea. It doesn't matter if you use mod_rewrite or not, even if your url looks like /controller/method/id/?some_long_text=some_variable - you will have them available under $_GET array, as long as there's properly formed querystring that can be parsed into $_GET. Test it before you try to fix it.

Comment: I did test that before I even made this post. This is the var_dump($_GET) for "/home/index/?test=willitwork": array(2) { ["controller"]=> string(4) "home" ["method"]=> string(5) "index" }

Comment: PHP parses the url that mod_rewrite made, not the one the sent from user.

Comment: Then apparently, your regexp for rewrite rules works in such way that it rewrites strings delimited with / into $_GET, which is apparently wrong. I'm using a similar scheme to yours, where I have "pretty" URls, however my $_GET works as intended.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no security concern, but your solution is quite fiddly. It's already possible to accomplish that with [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) (and [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) for splitting up the path). Or in your case just:

```
list($path, $qs) = explode("?", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 2);
parse_str($qs, $this->urlvars);
```

Comment: Thanks. Had no idea parse_str did that :D

Comment: this creates a "notice" if `REQUEST_URI` doesn't contain a `?`

Answer (score 21):

You also can do with php in built functions. Which will be an efficient way.

```
$urlArr=parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
parse_str($urlArr['query'], $output);

print_r($output);
```

Comment: +1 Probably more useful for most than the accepted answer. Path relative to the root in $urlArr[0] and a neat array with path, whole query, and separate query parameters in $output. Works well together with redirecting non-files and non-directories to index.php or similar using .htaccess.

Comment: simplest answer and far better, considering that accepted answer will throw warning, if there's no query part in the URI

Answer (score 3):

```
$the_array = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the [`$_GET` dictionary](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)?

Comment: Because I'm using mod_rewrite

Comment: If you're going after pretty URLs, often times all the querystring is compacted into directory levels; `this/is/the/uri/path` rather than `this?is=the&uri=path`. In the case of the former, in that you've rewritten it for prettiness, you can just `explode('/', $uri)` the REQUEST_URI

Comment: TomcatExodus: I'm doing both. My urls are /controller/method/id, and then any additional vars as ?var=something

Comment: you can pass query strings with mod_rewrite using QSA flag

Comment: I came here because for some reason $_GET and $_REQUEST where empty on my Wordpress while $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] was containing the required variables.